# What is Delphi error code e8000067?

Tags: ios, delphi, ios5, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I am building an app using Delphi XE8 and FireMonkey.

I've got it working on Android and am trying to get it working on an iPad.

The iPad is running OS X 5.1.1.
I've got a Debug Provisioning profile.

First, when I tried to run the application on the iPad, I got the error message "Unable to install package. (e8000007)". According to [Embarcadero's help page](http://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe8/mobdevsetup/ios/en/runiosdevicefailedhelppage.html), this was because I was targetting higher versions. So I went to "Project -> Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Linking", found that the minimum target OS was 7.0, and set it to 5.1.1 instead.

Now I'm getting

> Unable to launch process <ip address> using the parameters for the <profile name> profile.
>   The following error was returned: 'Unable to install package. (e8000067)'

This error code is not on the help page. I also don't find it when googling.

Since all these error codes start with "e", it's probably supposed to be a decimal number preceded by "e" for error. Searching for the hexadecimal equivalent of "8000067", i.e. "7A1243", only yields color codes.

I made a "Hello World" app, tried to run it on the iPad, and got the same problem.

What is Delphi error e8000067 ?

Comment: It is actually an iOS error. I see you found what it means. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks. Added that tag, so that others searching for this error code may find the solution more easily.

Comment: Good idea, indeed.

Comment: @Downvoters: would you like to explain what's so bad about this question? And what should be done to improve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this happens when you're compiling/linking for a 64 bits device, when your device is 32 bits.
When I chose to compile/link for a 32 bit device, the error went away.